# Configuring SPNEGO HTTP Servlet Filter

Tags: java, single-sign-on, kerberos, spnego

I'm trying to implement Java SSO for a Web Application using de SPNEGO library from SourceForge. The example of hello_spnego.jsp at http://spnego.sourceforge.net works fine, but there are some things that I don´t understand yet about the next parameters:

1. spnego.prompt.ntlm enables Basic Authentication for clients who don´t support Kerberos. Which is the value recommended for this parameter and why?
2. spnego.allow.basic offers Basic Authentication in addition of Kerberos authentication. I understand that Basic Authentication request credential is not very safe. Which is the value recommended for this parameter and why?
3. spnego.allow.unsecure.basic. I think that its value must be false if the Basic Authentication is enabled, but I´m not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of the parameters depend on your use case. If you have a strict kerberos/spnego only environment (safest, but all clients and users need to kerberos/spnego enabled) then use

- **spnego.prompt.ntlm=false** because we only allow kerberos

  s**pnego.allow.basic=false** because we only allow kerberos

  **spnego.allow.unsecure.basic=false** not relevant because spnego.allow.basic=false

If you want to allow additional authentication mechanisms in addition to kerberos/spnego than you have to decide which ones: NTLM and/or basic. NTLM is not supported by this library so Basic is the only one left.

- **spnego.prompt.ntlm=true** because we want to allow basic for non-spnego/NTLM only clients

  **spnego.allow.basic=true** because we want to allow basic for non-spnego clients

  **spnego.allow.unsecure.basic=false** we force basic authentication over HTTPS *(if you dont do this and set the value to true here, then you transmit your credentials unencrypted and in plaintext, thats not want you want i guess)*